# Shouldn't React-native render only changed components similar to how React works?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am new to the React scene but I am fairly familiar with its structure and at the very least how to make simple webapps using it but this got me scratching my head for hours

I am making a Tic Tac Toe using React-native, I currently experiment only on Android. These are the parts from my code that I think explains my situation

```
import Tile from "./Tile"

export default class Playground extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            board: [["?", "?", "?"], ["?", "?", "?"], ["?", "?", "?"]],
            turn: "X"
        }
    }

    move(x, y) {
        if (this.state.board[x][y] == "?") {
            var currentTurn = this.state.turn
            var currentBoard = this.state.board
            currentBoard[x][y] = this.state.turn
            this.setState({board: currentBoard});
            //this.isGameOver(x, y);
        }
    }

    isGameOver(x, y) {
        //Game Over Test
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Tile onPress={this.move.bind(this, 0, 0)} icon={this.state.board[0][0]}/>
                    <Tile onPress={this.move.bind(this, 0, 1)} icon={this.state.board[0][1]}/>
                    <Tile onPress={this.move.bind(this, 0, 2)} icon={this.state.board[0][2]}/>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Tile onPress={this.move.bind(this, 1, 0)} icon={this.state.board[1][0]}/>
                    <Tile onPress={this.move.bind(this, 1, 1)} icon={this.state.board[1][1]}/>
                    <Tile onPress={this.move.bind(this, 1, 2)} icon={this.state.board[1][2]}/>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Tile onPress={this.move.bind(this, 2, 0)} icon={this.state.board[2][0]}/>
                    <Tile onPress={this.move.bind(this, 2, 1)} icon={this.state.board[2][1]}/>
                    <Tile onPress={this.move.bind(this, 2, 2)} icon={this.state.board[2][2]}/>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

And of course the code for the tiles

```
export default class Tile extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    rand() {
        return Math.random() * 256;
    }

    randColor() {
        return "rgb(" + this.rand() + " ," + this.rand() + " ," + this.rand() + ")";
    }

    determineIcon() {
        if (this.props.icon == "X") {
            return (<Text>O</Text>)
        } else if (this.props.icon == "O") {
            return (<Text>X</Text>)
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log("Things are happening!")
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onPress} underlayColor={this.randColor()}>
                <View style={[styles.square, {backgroundColor: this.randColor()}]}>
                    {this.determineIcon()}
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    }
}
```

So what I noticed at first was that every time I clicked on a tile and it was successfully changed to an X ALL colours were regenerated again which made me realise that my app is re-rendering everything.

So I thought it was the fault of that random function and decided to have all squares be orange, but I wanted to know whether it was still re-rendering everything or just the tile I pressed, so I put that console log to see how many times is the rendering happening and to my dismay it happened 9 times.

I ended up removing the the onPress and icon properties from the 8 last tiles and turning them into completely static objects and changing board into a simple Boolean that I passed to the first tile. But no, it still rendered all 9 elements, again!

Can someone please explain to me, Shouldn't React-native render only changed components similar to how React works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently I've learned that when a new state is being set (or when props are changed), all your components in the hierarchy for this parent component will trigger the `render` function. This is true for `React` and not specific to `React-Native`; it happens because React's `shouldComponentUpdate()` defaults to `true`.

**This doesn't mean that the components are actually getting re-rendered again**. React is smart enough to figure out if it needs to update the UI or not as part of a process called "Reconciliation".

That said, if you have lots of components with a deep hierarchy, this behavior might put some stress on the JS thread. If you run into performance issues you can override `shouldComponentUpdate` to do your own logic, or just inherit from `React.PureComponent` instead of `React.Component` as it says in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate):

> If you determine a specific component is slow after profiling, you may
>   change it to inherit from React.PureComponent which implements
>   shouldComponentUpdate() with a shallow prop and state comparison. If
>   you are confident you want to write it by hand, you may compare
>   this.props with nextProps and this.state with nextState and return
>   false to tell React the update can be skipped.

Comment: PureComponent won't work here because of the bound click handler being a new reference on each render; more details: https://medium.com/@f.bagnardi/react-purecomponent-considered-harmful-8155b5c1d4bc#.4l6psfoqi

Comment: Thank you! So is there any way for me to figure out if my component is re-rendering in React-native? (I know how to do it using Chrome's Inspect > Render > Paint Flashing and to me it was a way to check whether or not I am doing things the right way)

Comment: @Mathspy generally speaking, you shouldn't be worried about re-renders, unless you bump into a performance hit. You can then optimize by using pure component. Once React decides that a component has changed and actually needs to render again, this information will pass the bridge to the native side and appropriate views will be refreshed.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand you're right, thanks for pointing it out and for the useful article! While using the pure component optimization in this case is not absolutely required, it could still easily be applied if you bind the handler in the constructor. Otherwise using pure component just won't do any optimization (same as using a regular component), please correct me if I'm wrong..

Comment: @Artal yeah. It's a little more complicated here because there's partial application of event handles, so you need a reference to each of them; but nothing memoization can't solve.